# How can I use the angular custom webpack proxy config to return mock data

Tags: angular, webpack, proxy

Inside my Angular 9 application im using RESTful API calls to fetch data from external server.

During development, I want to fake this interface to the server via a mock concept.

Currently I am using the `HttpInterceptor`-interface technique of Angular but this has the disadvantage of not seeing any request inside the browser.

That said, I would like to use a custom webpack proxy (via `@angular-builders/custom-webpack`) to catch the request via
`bypass: function(rawRequest: IncomingMessage, rawResponse: ServerResponse; proxyConfig?: any)`
function, handle this request by providing all neccessary information about the request to the mock (by filling `HttpRequest<any>` from `IncomingMessage`-object) and return the `ServerResponse` object.

My current code look like this:

Mock:

```
interface BackendMock {
  url: string;
  method: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE';

  handle(request: HttpRequest<any>): HttpResponse<any>;
}

export const DATA_MOCK: BackendMock = {
  url: '/api/data',
  method: 'GET',
  handle(request: HttpRequest<any>): HttpResponse<any> {
    const response = new HttpResponse({
      ...request,
      body: ['Some', 'Data'],
    });
    return response;
  },
};
```

Current interceptor:

```
@Injectable()
export class MockInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    for (const mock of ALL_MOCKS) {
      if (this.mockMatchesRequest(mock, req)) {
        return of(mock.handle(req));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Custom Webpack config with proxy:

```
import { IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from 'http';

async function readDataFromRequest(rawRequest: IncomingMessage): Promise<string> {
  return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    rawRequest.on('data', rawData => {
      resolve(rawData.toString());
    });
  });
}

const proxies: any[] = [
  {
    context: ['/api/*'],
    selfHandleResponse: true,
    bypass: async function (rawRequest: IncomingMessage, rawResponse: ServerResponse, proxyOptions: any) {
      const rawBody = await readDataFromRequest(rawRequest);
      // const httpRequest = new HttpRequest<any>({ body: JSON.parse(rawBody) })
      // const mock = getMockByRequest(rawRequest);
      // const httpResponse = mock.handle(httpRequest);
      // updateResponse(rawResponse, httpResponse);
      rawResponse.end(rawBody);
      return rawResponse;
    },
  },
];


module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: proxies
  }
};
```

Actually, the proxy works well. But it's giving me some weird error:

> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Steps to reproduce:

1. Angular-application set up and executing an HTTP request to `http://localhost:5000/api/data`
2. Added Custom weback config to Angular project
3. Configured proxy of `/api/*` with bypass function
4. Reading body from **REQUEST** `request.read(1234)` or `request.on('data', (data) => ...)`
5. Writing status, headers and body to **RESPONSE** via `res.end(JSON.stringify({ name: 'Hello World' }));`

Does anyone know about this? What am I doing wrong?